# How do you declare and consume marker interface in f#?

Tags: f#

How do you replicate this in F#?

```
interface IMarker
{
    // No members here
}

class MyClass : IMarker
{
// can contain code
}
```

Update:
The following code does define marker interface, but none of the answers so far manages to producde class that implements this marker interface (see MyClass above)

```
type IMarker = interface     end
```

Comment: The .NET coding guidelines recommend against this pattern. Don't know why.

Comment: <sarcasm>Because it's so much easier and faster to use reflection to discover attributes</sarcasm>.

Answer (score 20):

An old question, but the required syntax (F# 2.0) for this special case is actually:

```
type IMarker = interface end

type Marker =
  class
    interface IMarker
  end
```

Or alternatively (including a constructor for Marker):

```
type IMarker = interface end

type Marker() =
    interface IMarker
```

Just writing

```
type Marker =
  interface IMarker
```

is not possible because it looks like you want to create a new interface type.

Answer (score 11):

```
type IMarker = interface     end
type MyClass = interface IMarker
```

(Update)

F# always defines interfaces implicitly , you need to cast to the interface in order to use it.

[Why F# interface differs greatly from C#](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/7523.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In order to get an empty type, I believe you will have to revert to the non-light syntax (interface...end).

```
#light

type IMarker = 
    interface
    end

type Marker =
    interface IMarker
```

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head (without firing up Visual Studio):

```
type IMarker ;

type MyClass =
  interface IMarker
```